# Разлогиниться через oauth VK API

Tags: вконтакте, oauth

oauth.vk.com/logout не работает. Какие еще варианты есть?

Comment: Чуть подробнее: какое приложение (сторонний сервер, Standalone?) Вы в итоге получаете access_token. Ну, забудьте его, например.

Comment: Standalone. Да, получаю токен. Забуду я лучше ваш странный комментарий

Comment: Что вы ожидаете в результате «logout»?

Comment: Очевидно - возможность залогиниться другому пользователю

Comment: Как бы это странно ни звучало – забудьте в приложении токен, который получили, и сбросьте приложение в начальное состояние. Поздравляю – вы разлогинились.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27485/discussion-between-swiftstudier-and-sergiks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Предположу*, что вы используете для авторизации веб-компонент, чтобы зайти в ВК и выдать разрешение вашему Standalone приложению. И вопрос ваш не про OAuth-logout, если так можно выразиться, а про выход в этом веб-компоненте.

Прямой ответ на ваш первоначальный вопрос - всё тот же: забудьте полученный access_token.

А как заставить веб-компонент сбросить сессию и стереть все куки – зависит от его конкретной реализации.

**Обновление**

Ссылки типа `vk.com/logout` мне неизвестно. В десктоп- и мобильной версиях сайта ссылка выхода содержит hash сессии, и без параметров не работает. Есть метод OpenAPI [`VK.Auth.logout()`](https://vk.com/dev/openapi_auth), но вряд ли ваше приложение использует OpenApi.

«Сброс кук - колхозный способ.»

Это ваш способ. Реализуйте именно его.

Comment: Сброс кук - колхозный способ. Неужели нельзя никак это ссылочно-вкшно сделать?

Comment: А если кто-то стащит токен, то значит пусть пользуется - он-то его забывать вряд ли собирается. Должна быть какая-то нормальная возможность же?

Comment: Если предположить, что автор приложения *злодей*, то и все предоставленные им методы для выхода – ненадёжны. Тогда **длинный способ:** ВКонтакте зайти в Приложения - Мои Приложения - [Настройки](https://vk.com/apps?act=settings), и в списке «Убрать» все ненужные приложения. **Короткий способ** – поменять свой пароль ВКонтакте. При этом **все** выданные ранее токены теряют актуальность.